# Infineon XMC1100 Event Request Unit ERU

Tags: embedded, cortex-m

What is the need of Event Request Unit (ERU)? What is the difference between ERU and NVIC. why we are using ERU instead of NVIC?

Answer (score 1):

From this [manufacturer's application note](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-ERU-XMC1000_XMC4000-AP32306-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4624e765da5014ed914180d1c24), it is clear the the ERU can trigger direct *hardware actions* (such as ADC conversion) in response to *hardware events*.  An interrupt controller specifically triggers *software handlers* in response to hardware events.

The ERU has a concept of "action providers", this includes an IRQ (so the CPU may be an action provider just like an interrupt controller), but not only that. It is also not not the same as DMA (although that is also a possible action provider), but rather an event signalling mechanism that avoids the bus contention that occurs with DMA.  Essentially the ERU allows zero software, CPU and bus overhead for peripheral to peripheral signalling.